# How to use a new token to push to github?

Tags: git, github

In order to push something to github it looks like I need to create a new token (again...). But what that new token, how do I tell `git` to use a new token? What command do I have to use to use the new token?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `git` does not provide a 'nice' way to update your token. But here is how you can do it:

1. You remove the old origin

   ```
   git remote remove origin
   ```
2. You add the new origin with the token integrated, i.e.

   ```
   git remote add origin https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git
   ```

so it looks like e.g.

```
git remote add origin https://ghp_hgv674bbdgdytewyeegegd@github.com/alex526/myrepo.git
```

**Hint:**

Sometimes this procedure will not work.

Answer (score -1):

From the GitHub doc :

> Once you have a token, you can enter it instead of your password when
> performing Git operations over HTTPS.

so just make sure that the old **token** is no longer cached in your laptop and use the token generated as a password

you can find in the link how to create a **new** **token**

Comment: ... and how to do that exactly...?